# Callback event from native iOS in react native

Tags: javascript, objective-c, swift, react-native, callback

In my react native app, there is a screen in which native iOS component is rendered. The screen has rendering iOS native code.

I need to send a callback event from Native iOS to react native js code and fetch that event.

I tried some solutions but none work for me.

Here is screen code:

```
<View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#FFF'}}>
        <NavigationBar
          style={{
            borderBottomColor: '#CBC8C8',
            borderBottomWidth: 1 / PixelRatio.get(),
          }}
          title={{
            title: 'Demo',
            style:{color: 'black', fontFamily: 'Lato-Regular', fontSize: horizScale(16)}
          }}
          leftButton={<TouchableOpacity style={{padding: 6, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}} onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.goBack()
          }}>
            <FAIcon name='angle-left' size={horizScale(30)} style={{color: primaryColor, marginLeft: 10}} />
          </TouchableOpacity>}
        />
        <NativeIOSView style={{flex: 2, backgroundColor: '#FFF'}} />
      </View>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "I tried some solutions but none work for me." - please share.

Comment: Yeah. Can you please share what all you have tried?